# Firebase Storage Task as Observable

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, observable, firebase-storage

I am trying to use Observable to do a "Monitor Upload Progress" as per [Firebase's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files). Nevertheless, it seems that this might work for Ionic 1 but how can I make it work for Ionic 2 using Typescript?

Comment: It is just a javascript no? Typescript is a superset of JS.That means you can run any JS code inside the TS. So you can implement it with TS too.try that and if you have any specific question come back here again.

Comment: @Sampath, I actually copy and paste the code into my project but my problem is that when I am trying to subscribe to it, nothing is returned to the function that subscribe it.

Comment: Firebase works with Promises, not Observables. (when you see `then()` it's a promise, when you see `subscribe()` it's an observable :). You can use [fromPromise()](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromPromise), like this `Observable.fromPromise(ref.put(file))` for start...

Comment: Yes, you have to use `Promises` with storage API. But in the future, you'll have `observable` with `Angularfire2`.